# Ruby cgi needs to reload apache for new value?

Tags: ruby, cgi, passenger

I have phusion-passenger installed with apache on Ubuntu.  In my config.ru, I have the following code:

```
require 'cgi'

$tpl = CGI.new['myvar'] + '.rb'

app = proc do |env|
    [200, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, [$tpl]]
end
run app
```

So then when I go to my browser at `http://localhost/?myvar=hello`, I see the word `hello` printed out, which is fine.  Then I change the url to `http://localhost/?myvar=world`, but the page still shows `hello`.  Only after I reload apache will the page show `world`.

Before using phusion-passenger, I was using mod_ruby with apache. If I remember correctly, I didn't need to restart apache to get the CGI variable to print the updated value.

I'm not stuck on needing to use CGI.  I just want to be able to grab query string parameters without having to reload apache each time.

I'm not using rails or Sinatra because i'm just trying to wrap my head around the Ruby language and what phusion-passenger with apache is all about.

Comment: "I'm not using rails or Sinatra because i'm just trying to wrap my head around the Ruby language and what phusion-passenger with apache is all about." You're really going about it a difficult way then. We seldom use Rack, we use Sinatra, Padrino or Rails and treat Rack as an invisible layer for most simple things, Rack gets useful when we need to mess with the data flow between the HTTPd and the control layer. Ruby is NOT Rack, Rack is the middleware between a HTTPd and a Ruby control layer, like Sinatra.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this behavior makes sense. Because `$tpl` is set only once when the file is loaded, what happens when the first request is served. After that - in following requests - only the `proc` is called, but that does not change `$tpl` anymore.

Instead of using plain `CGI`, I would do it with a very simple `Rack` app:

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/server'

class Server
  def self.call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    tpl = "#{req.params['myvar']}.rb"
    [200, {}, [tpl]]
  end
end

run Server
```

Comment: Ok thanks.  I've been trying within the proc just now, but it still retains the value of the first time I loaded the page.  Can you think of any other ideas? In the end, my objective is to pass different variables each time through the url to my ruby script

Comment: I updated my answer. My first solition did not solve the problem. It just moved it to an other line, since the `proc` was also defined when the server starts.

Comment: i just tried the lambda version of your code and still the same issue.  Do i really need to learn rack?  I was overwhelmed just trying to get Sinatra to work...