# ruby equivalent of php's $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: ruby, passenger

I'm new to ruby.  I have phusion-passenger installed with apache on Ubuntu.  Is there a ruby equivalent for php's $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or any of php's $_SERVER variables?

I am not using Sinatra or rails because i'm just trying to learn how to use ruby first.

Comment: If you are trying to learn just Ruby, then you shouldn't even need to use Passenger or Apache, you only need Ruby. The variables you're after are standard and are passed from Apache via the environment table, so, yes, Ruby can see them by looking at `ENV`, but you should rely on the framework to retrieve those and pass them to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a simple Rack server like this:

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/server'

class EnvInspector
  def self.call(env)
    [200, {}, [env.inspect]]
  end
end

run EnvInspector
```

it would return you something like this that tells you all the keys in the `env` variable:

```
{
  "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"thin 1.4.1 codename Chromeo",
  "SERVER_NAME"=>"localhost",
  "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x007fa1bce039f8>,
  "rack.version"=>[1, 0],
  "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>,
  "rack.multithread"=>false,
  "rack.multiprocess"=>false,
  "rack.run_once"=>false,
  "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET",
  "REQUEST_PATH"=>"/favicon.ico",
  "PATH_INFO"=>"/favicon.ico",
  "REQUEST_URI"=>"/favicon.ico",
  "HTTP_VERSION"=>"HTTP/1.1",
  "HTTP_HOST"=>"localhost:8080",
  "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"keep-alive",
  "HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"*/*",
  "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11",
  "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip,deflate,sdch",
  "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"en-US,en;q=0.8",
  "HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"=>"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
  "HTTP_COOKIE"=> "_gauges_unique_year=1;  _gauges_unique_month=1",
  "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2",
  "SERVER_PORT"=>"8080",
  "QUERY_STRING"=>"",
  "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1",
  "rack.url_scheme"=>"http",
  "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"",
  "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"127.0.0.1",
  "async.callback"=>#<Method: Thin::Connection#post_process>,
  "async.close"=>#<EventMachine::DefaultDeferrable:0x007fa1bce35b88
}
```

So `env['REQUEST_URI']` would be the equivalent to php's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

See http://hawkins.io/2012/07/rack_from_the_beginning/ for more examples how to use Rack.

Comment: @John: I updated my code. Please change `[200, {}, env.inspect]` to `[200, {}, [env.inspect]]`.

Comment: Again I updated my answer (last line of the `config.ru`). Seems like the Rack API has change significately since the blog post was written. I am sorry, but I am unable to test the code on my current machine in the moment.

Comment: Alright! It worked.  It also provides me with new query string values with each page load, which answers my other question.  Thanks for helping out a newb!

Comment: Here's the link to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412341/ruby-cgi-needs-to-reload-apache-for-new-value .  You can just say that the answer to the question is also the answer to this question, then I can accept it.  Otherwise, if I answer my own question, I have to wait 2 days to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not using Sinatra or rails because i'm just trying to learn how to use ruby first.

Ruby does not presume a web server. It is a general-purpose programming language that stands on its own. If you were using a web development framework, it would provide you with access to such data.

Both Rails and Sinatra use Rack, which uses a [request object](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request) in order to access this data. The `REQUEST_URI` variable corresponds to the path including the query string; the [`fullpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request#fullpath-instance_method) method is used to access it:

```
# get '/articles'
request.fullpath # => '/articles'

# get '/articles?page=2'
request.fullpath # => '/articles?page=2'
```

The basic API is the same in all those frameworks. For reference:

- [`Rack::Request`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request)
- [Rails Guides - The `request` Object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object)
- [`ActionDispatch::Request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html)
- [`Sinatra::Request`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sinatra/sinatra/Sinatra/Request)
- [Sinatra Getting Started - Accessing the Request Object](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object)

Comment: Thanks.  I've been losing days trying to distinguish the roles and responsibilities of passenger, apache, ruby, Sinatra...so when something goes wrong, I'm often going down the wrong path in my troubleshooting. That's why I figure maybe I should just stick to the essentials, get use to that before learning the next thing.

Comment: Just work with Ruby and Sinatra for now, and forget about wiring in Apache and Passenger. Once you understand how Ruby, Rack, and Sinatra, Padrino or Rails work, then the rest will be easier to understand.